# Separate numbers, unknowns and mathematical symbols

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this: `x+1=13-x`

What I have to do, is separate the unknown (`x`) from mathematical symbols (`+`, `-`, `*`, `:` or `/`) and numbers. That means that the left side of the string would be an array like `[x,+,1]` and the right side: `[13,-,x]`.

Before this, I was only working with one-digit numbers, so, I just used `str_split()` function, but, now I would like to use RegEx which I am not good at.

Comment: Why don't you show us some things you've tried, and how they've gone wrong?

Comment: Have you tried anything regarding regex? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ provides a good introduction.

Comment: Regex?  No, you need a parser.  And certainly there are more symbols that arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to adapt this a bit, but try this:

```
<?php
$data = "a+123=x-23";
$arr = preg_split("/\\b/", $data);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

```
$ php t.php
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => a
    [2] => +
    [3] => 123
    [4] => =
    [5] => x
    [6] => -
    [7] => 23
    [8] => 
)
```

As you can see, the individual components are visible in the resulting array. You'll need to  take care of whitespace issues.

Comment: You can use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to make [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) only return non-empty parts.